# How to convert numeric string to int in a RDD of string words and numbers?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

So I have an RDD with words and numbers in strings format that i've split and removed punctuation and whitespaces:

```
['Hi', 'today', 'is', 'a', 'great', 'day', 'to', 'gather', 'flowers', 'lets', 'collect', '50', 'Roses', '400', 'Tulips', 'and', '20', 'Sunflowers', 'today']
```

I want to count the number of distinct words and sort them in alphabetical and number order so the output would look something like this:

```
(20, 1)
(50, 1)
(400, 1)
('Hi', 1)
('today, 2)
```

I tried using sortby but I suspect because the numbers are strings, it is only sorting by the first number as such the number 400 comes before 50. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to split the RDD in two and perform your reduction and sorting, then union the result afterwards

```
import re
numbers = (rdd.filter(lambda l: re.match('^[0-9]+$', l))
              .map(lambda l: (int(l), 1))
              .reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)
              .sortByKey())
text = (rdd.filter(lambda l: not re.match('^[0-9]+$', l))
           .map(lambda l: (l, 1))
           .reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)
           .sortByKey())
```

Then union both:

```
numbers.union(text).collect()
```

```
[(20, 1),
 (50, 1),
 (400, 1),
 ('Hi', 1),
 ('Roses', 1),
 ('Sunflowers', 1),
 ('Tulips', 1),
 ('a', 1),
 ('and', 1),
 ('collect', 1),
 ('day', 1),
 ('flowers', 1),
 ('gather', 1),
 ('great', 1),
 ('is', 1),
 ('lets', 1),
 ('to', 1),
 ('today', 2)]
```

This is because you can't sort a flat RDD with different comparisons.